# What's the best way to define Cartesian products as operating on classes? Is there such a way?

Tags: set-theory

I've been working on something in modal logic, and have recently found myself wanting to speak about Cartesian products operating on classes.  But there are obvious obstacles to talking about such things.  For one thing, even assuming that there *are* classes is a fraught assumption.  But suppose we're working in a set theory, *e.g.* NBG, in which there are.  (Fans of different sorts of ZF can paraphrase.)  For another thing, Cartesian products are usually *defined* as operating on sets: A x B = {<a, b>: a ∊ A and b ∊ B}.  But it seems perfectly possible to extend our definition of Cartesian products so that they also operate on classes: for any classes A and B, A x B = the class of all the 'tuples <a, b> s.t. a ∊ A and b ∊ B.   (Obviously we could make that definition more formal; but equally obviously - I hope! - we don't need to for my purposes here.)  What I'm wondering, then, is whether there are further obstacles to speaking of Cartesian products as operating on classes.  (Or whether the responses to objections considered here are unsound.)  Anyone's thoughts are very welcome.

Comment: Hi Didion, welcome to MO -- working in [MK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse–Kelley_set_theory) (a small step up in consistency strength from NBG), it is perfectly fine to define the Cartesian product of classes in the way you suggest. If you're just wanting a situation where you can quantify over proper classes when using the comprehension axiom, I would recommend working in MK.

Comment: Dear Alec: thank you so much!  If it's not too much to ask, why are we able to do this in Morse-Kelley but not in NBG?  Apologies for asking such a doubtlessly basic question.

Comment: No problem, the question is a good one; it has to do with how the axiom of [comprehension](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/axiom+of+separation) (sometimes called separation) is phrased. In ZFC it says that any formula where the parameters are sets has a corresponding ‘set of objects satisfying the formula’, and in ZFC sets are the only objects of discourse. In NBG we have classes to talk about, but we still restrict the axiom of comprehension to say that for any formula whose parameters are *sets* there is a *class* of objects satisfying the property. MK goes whole hog with comprehension, (cont)

Comment: asserting that for any formula whose parameters are classes there exists a class of objects satisfying the property; this is, for example, what you suggested above with $A\times B=\{(a,b):a\in A\wedge b\in B\}$ where $A$ and $B$ (both classes a-priori) show up in the formula defining the class under consideration. This apparently small difference is actually what makes MK stronger in consistency strength than ZFC or GBC — it enables MK to prove the consistency of both of those theories, which anoints it a stronger theory in terms of consistency strength.

Comment: @Didion. In NBG, the Cartesian product of two classes A and B is defined in precisely the same manner as as it is for sets in ZF. There is no reason to move to MK to do so. For a discussion of this see, for example, pp. 182-183 of Elliot Mendelson's "Introduction to Mathematical Logic, 3rd Edition", 1987.  There are later editions which no doubt discuss this, but I'm not sure of the page numbers for them. Moreover, the definition is discussed in most discussions of NBG .

Comment: I agree with @PhilipEhrlich that the difference between NBG and MK is irrelevant to this question. The definition of $A\times B$ works even in the weaker theory NBG. On the other hand, if you want the operation $\times$ (acting on proper classes) to be an element of the universe of discourse, then not even the stronger theory MK can achieve that; you'd need a theory of hyperclasses (collections of classes).

Comment: @AlecRhea Didion wasn't asking what the difference between NBG and MK is, they asked why the difference is relevant

Comment: As you can see, these questions are just fine on this site; I will defer to Philip and Andreas on this subject as they have been thinking about it longer, but I am curious how comprehension in NBG can be used for the definition in this post.

Comment: @Alec Rhea. The formula that defines membership in the Cartesian Product only involves quantification over set variables. As such, the Class Existence Theorem, which is a consequence of the Predicative Comprehension Axiom, implies the existence of the Cartesian Product. As usual, Extensionality implies uniqueness. For details, see the above reference to Mendelson or to subsequent editions.

Comment: @PhilipEhrlich Ah, I must be misunderstanding what it means to ‘quantify over’ something in a formula to define a class — my understanding was that any variables that appeared in the formula defining a class are the variables being quantified over. But now that I wrote it out I think I can see my error; in the case of the Cartesian definition product listed above, the only variables are $a$ and $b$ while $A$ and $B$ are fixed classes whose *members* we are quantifying over, and those members are trivially already sets. Thank you!

Comment: This has been incredibly helpful to me!  So thanks to everyone for their comments: I'm grateful to all of you.